# Labelling points for classification in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run multiple classifiers on [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EricChiang/churn/master/data/churn.csv) telecom dataset to predict churn. So far, I've loaded my dataset into a Spark RDD, but I'm not sure how I can select one column to be a label - in this case, the last column. Not asking for code, but a short explanation on how RDDs and LabeledPoint work together. I looked at examples provided in the official Spark github, but they seem to use the libsvm format.

Question: how does LabeledPoint work, and how can I specify what my label is?

My code so far, if it helps:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.{RandomForestClassificationModel, RandomForestClassifier}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StandardScaler
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.{SVMModel, SVMWithSGD, LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel, NaiveBayes, NaiveBayesModel}

object{
   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //setting spark context
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Churn")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    //loading and mapping data into RDD
    val csv = sc.textFile("file://filename.csv")
    val data = csv.map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim))
    /* computer learns which points are features and labels here */
}
}
```

The dataset looks like this:

```
State,Account Length,Area Code,Phone,Int'l Plan,VMail Plan,VMail Message,Day Mins,Day Calls,Day Charge,Eve Mins,Eve Calls,Eve Charge,Night Mins,Night Calls,Night Charge,Intl Mins,Intl Calls,Intl Charge,CustServ Calls,Churn?
KS,128,415,382-4657,no,yes,25,265.100000,110,45.070000,197.400000,99,16.780000,244.700000,91,11.010000,10.000000,3,2.700000,1,False.
OH,107,415,371-7191,no,yes,26,161.600000,123,27.470000,195.500000,103,16.620000,254.400000,103,11.450000,13.700000,3,3.700000,1,False.
NJ,137,415,358-1921,no,no,0,243.400000,114,41.380000,121.200000,110,10.300000,162.600000,104,7.320000,12.200000,5,3.290000,0,False.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question so far ?

Comment: I'll edit it in to be more clear - my question is: how does LabeledPoint work, and how can I specify what my label is?

Comment: A LalebedPoint is a numeric vector with a label. In order to convert your current data to LabeledPoints you'll need to do some feature engineering and some transformations. I suggest you read the whole MLlib and ML documentation to start so you can understand its DataTypes, Transformers, etc. as your question is too broad to answer within the scope of SO.

Comment: Can you update/fix the link to the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide what your features are: for example the phone number will not be a feature. So, some columns will be dropped. Then, you want to transform the string columns to numbers. Yes, you could do it with ML transformers, but it's an overkill in this situation. I'd do it like this (showing the logic on a single line of your data):

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

val line = "NJ,137,415,358-1921,no,no,0,243.400000,114,41.380000,121.200000,110,10.300000,162.600000,104,7.320000,12.200000,5,3.290000,0,False"
val arrl = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
val mr = Map("no"-> "0.0", "yes"-> "0.0", "False"->"0.0", "True" ->"1.0")
val stringvec = Array( arrl(2), mr(arrl(4)), mr(arrl(5))   ) ++ arrl.slice(6, 20)

val label = mr(arrl(20)).toDouble
val vec = stringvec.map(_.toDouble)
LabeledPoint( label, Vectors.dense(vec))
```

So, to answer your question: a labeled point is the target variable (in this case, the last column (as a Double), has the customer churned or not), plus the vector of numeric (Double) features describing the customer (`vec` in this case).